# How to setup $JAVA_HOME, because Maven is 1.6, and you are using Java 1.7 or higher?

Tags: java, maven

I have a configuration problem, from this code,
https://github.com/plum-umd/java-sketch.

Here, I must set $JAVA_HOME, because:

"One possible issue you may encounter while
building sketch-frontend is the inconsistent
Java version in Maven, e.g.,
Maven refers to Java 1.6 while the main
Java you're using is 1.7 or higher.
In that case, set up $JAVA_HOME properly."

I should setup $JAVA_HOME, but to what value?

## Here is my JAVA,

$ java -version

## openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-120.04,
mixed mode, sharing)

## The current error when executing the program is:

$./sketch
SKETCH version 1.7.0
your java version is out of date. Version 1.6 required

What value should $JAVA_HOME take, in this case?

Answer (score -1):

The assumption here is that you have **multiple** java versions installed. You should set up JAVA_HOME to point to a Java 1.6 (= Java 6) installation. The version you have is Java 14.